# Regex of Zipcode of MS Word

Tags: regex, windows, ms-word

Currently, I have a list of 43k zipcodes.

I'm trying to use ms word regex modify the date from looking like:
[image: img1]

To look like: `00631` WITHOUT any quotes around it.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about MS Word, but regex is quite simple - `(\")(\d{5})(\")`
This is in case ZIP is 5 digits in quotes